# print pdf file in acrobat reader using javascript and close it

Tags: asp.net, acrobat

we are displaying a reporting services report as a pdf document in acrobat reader. when the user clicks on the print in the acrobat reader, I will like to print the report and close the report. The user should be able to print the report only once.

Comment: "The user should be able to print only once" - Are you trying to do this as a security measure?

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that this is possible. You need much more access then browser can give. May be ActiveX or browser add-in can help...

Anyways, browsers have some limited support for printing. Check [out](http://www.bing.com/search?q=JavaScript+print&src=IE-SearchBox&FORM=IE8SRC):

```
window.print();
```

I am not sure if it works in all browsers, though.

Answer (score 0):

This *is* possible to do. You simply need to add

```
this.print();
```

as a "JavaScript PDF action" to the "open" event of the document. Unfortunately, if your report generator is creating the PDFs internally you might not be able to inject the necessary code.